# Where's the design view for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio

I have been using VS 2012 since this morning, when I updated to 2013 through my school's dreamspark thing.

Now I can't find where the design view button is on this version. It used to be on the lower left corner.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Select Web Development Environment Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521558%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for Visual studio. It also seems to be a bug with Visual studio installation, reported [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796625/visual-studio-2013-missing-design-source-and-split-buttons)

You can also try:

Right click on the file and click "Open With...", it will show you following window. 
Select **HTML Editor**

[image]

Currently it appears that you have opened the file in XML (Text) Editor and somehow set it to default by mistake.

Comment: I have HTML Editor selected. But I don't see the option popping up.

Comment: Is it Visual studio 2012 or 13 ? you have 13 in title and 12 in question

Comment: @trama, oh yes, you are right, I didn't read the whole thing, check this https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/796625/visual-studio-2013-missing-design-source-and-split-buttons, it seems to be a bug in VS installation, also try [selecting your environment for web development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521558(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: It didn't seem to work. I am just going to go back to 2012. Thanks anyways.